# Node.JS and pgpool versions

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, pgpool

I am trying to call postgress via pgpool (pgpool-II) using node.js 'pg' module. If anyone had got that kind of setup working, what is the right version of pgpool-II and right version of 'pg' that are known to work together? From what [I found](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/513) some versions of pg-pool have a regression with parameters so you cannot call them from pg (which is what I am experiencing right now).

Comment: It might help if you included some specifics - your current versions, the exact text of any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.3.1 of pgpool seem to work well with node.JS. Version 3.3.2 has bugs, do not use it.